# How important is td(on), (off) and tr rise/fall. How close do they need to be for a primary side mosfet

Tags: power, mosfet

I have a power supply with a mosfet on the primary side that has failed. I am attempting to repair it, however, I am having difficulty finding a replacement. The part number svd4n65f and has a **td(on) of 20** and a **td(off) of 128**. The **trise is 19.3** and the **tfall is 20.** The other specs have been easier but not with the above specs.
They are **VDSS = 650V**, 
         **Id = 4A**, 
         **Rds(on) = 3 ohm**, 
         **Idm = 16A**, 
         **Vgs(th) = 3V**.

I have a couple of mosfets I was thinking of trying but I wanted to ask about the td and trise/tfall first.

The closest one has a **td(on) of 6** and a **td(off) of 58.5** The **trise is 2.5** and the **tfall is 9.5**.

If you can advise on this I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 2):

MOSFET switching time is really dependent on the driver (current capability and any added series resistance).

Total gate charge \$Q_G\$ (usually measured in nC - and specified under comparable conditions) is a more important factor when comparing for replacement purposes.

Comment: The total Gate Charges are as follows....  The original parts Qg is **15.8 nC** tested @ **VDS=520V,ID=4.0A**  The replacement **Qg = 20 nC** tested @ **VDD = 400 V, ID = 4.4 A**

Comment: @CollinSmith Pretty close, but not as good. The higher Vdd means the gate charge is less, but not by a huge amount.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I just need it to perform close to as well I suppose. It is powering an external harddrive cage that would power a single drive. I am not sure of the total draw but I would assume since this is on the primary side that there is circuitry after the secondary that would clean up any noise. I also know what they say about assuming though, lol. I know I could just buy another power supply ***(ICY Dock Weihai SW34-1202A02-S4 4 Pins Power Adapter)*** but I enjoy the challenge and learning or refreshing my skills.

Answer (score 1):

The rise and fall times (assuming the drive is capable of sink/sourcing the gate charge needed) affect the switching losses of the device, then switching transients and EMC

The (possible) new device switches faster so the switching losses would be improved.
However, aspects of the layout could cause incease in turn-off overshoot which could result in avalanche or other ringing.
Equally the higher edge rate will increase the frequencies that are conducted and/or radiated.

I am not saying the replacement part will cause issues (not enough information) just stating the three main considerations with regards to switching speeds

Comment: Thank you for a very thoughtful answer. Unfortunately, I took electronics in 1993 and I have been away from it for quite awhile. A basic understanding of theory and the soldering skills that are needed have been retained, but for the rest I rely on Google. Much of what you said I would need to research to understand. If you have any IT questions I am your man. ;-)